# Реализация метода strip через регулярные выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть код

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'^( )*([^ ])*( )*$')
>>> regex.search('   asdfgh   ').group(2)
'h'
```

Почему результат `'h'`, а не `'asdfgh'`?

P.S. Полный текст задачи:

> Regex version of strip(). Write a function that takes a string and
>   does the same thing as the  strip() string method. If no other
>   arguments are passed other than the string to strip, then whitespace
>   characters will be removed from the beginning and end of the string.
>   Otherwise, the characters specified in the second argument to the
>   function will be removed from the string.
>
> Версия функции `strip` с использованием регулярных выражений. Напишите функцию, которая принимает строку и возвращает строку такую же, как полученная с помощью метода `strip` для строк. При использовании с единственным аргументом, функция должна убирать все пробельные символы в начале и конце строки, при использовании с двумя аргументами, должны убираться символы, указанные во втором аргументе.

Comment: "почему" - потому что в группе у вас только один символ. Количество групп определяется не числом совпадений с группой, а числом скобочек. Поэтому у вас будет только 3 группы, хотя групп по одному символу можно было и больше создать. Почему `h`, а не, например, `a` (первое совпадение для группы) - не скажу, возможно в стандарте так прописано, возможно просто реализация такая, что прошлые совпадающие выражения вытесняются из данной группы

Comment: @pynix сорри, но Вы ответили как верный НЕВЕРНЫЙ ответ, ибо `strip` работает не так.

Comment: Действительно, я проверил только для строки, состоящей из одного слова с пробелами по краям. Для строк, где есть внутренний пробел, такой метод не работает

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что текст задачи сформулирован на английском языке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложенные варианты не справляются со строкой `" some text "`, не говоря уж о том, что `[^ ]` запросто включает табуляции и др. пробельные символы.
Правильное решение:

```
p = re.compile("^(\s+)((.+)(?=\S).)(\s+)$")
print p.search(" some text\t of several words \n").group(2)
```

Даже это не справляется со строкой `" some\ntext "`. (кстати, я не понимаю, почему). Спасибо @BOROH, чтобы справиться с переносами строки внутри текста, надо модифицировать регулярку следующим образом:

```
p = re.compile("^(\s+)((.+)(?=\S).)(\s+)$", re.DOTALL)
p.search(" some\ntext ").group(2) --> "some\ntext"
```

Все равно останется особый случай пустой строки `""` или строки состоящей только из пробельных символов (на выходе должна быть пустая строка).

Совсем уж правильно, вероятно, будет так:

```
r1 = re.compile("^\s+")
r2 = re.compile("\s+$")
s = re.sub(p1, '', re.sub(p2, '', "\tsome\n\ttext\n"))
s == "some\n\ttext" # True
```

в итоге:

```
def strip(s):
     strip.r1 = re.compile("^\s+")
     strip.r2 = re.compile("\s+$")
     return re.sub(strip.r1, '', re.sub(strip.r2, '', s))

strip("\tsome\ntext \t") # -> "some\ntext"
```

Добавляем второй аргумент:

```
def strip(s, symbols=r"\s"):
     strip.r1 = re.compile("^[{}]+".format(symbols))
     strip.r2 = re.compile("[{}]+$".format(symbols))
     return re.sub(strip.r1, '', re.sub(strip.r2, '', s))

strip("\tsome\ntext \t") # -> "some\ntext"
```

Comment: *Даже это не справляется со строкой* - а что ожидается на выходе? `"some\ntext"`? Ну тогда в точке проблема - она не учитывает переносы строк, чтобы это исправить, достаточно флаг [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#contents-of-module-re) поставить (или `re.S`)

Comment: @BOPOH, спс, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @BOPOH, ну `" some\ntext ".strip()"` выдает именно `"some\ntext"`

Comment: Вариант со вторым аргументом ошибочен если передать метасимволы, предварительно необходимо делать `re.escape`

Comment: @ReinRaus, можно чуть подробнее? В квадратных скобках большинство метасимволов игнорируются, по крайней мере с `symbols='\tx.\d'` работает как надо. Да надо аккуратно с `^` а что еще? В целом Вы правы, возможность такого нужно учесть.

Comment: `strip( text, "a-z" )` если делать полноценную реализацию `strip`, то это должны быть литералы `a`, `-` и `z`

Comment: @ReinRaus, да Вы правы. Впрочем решается передачей 'a\-z' в качестве аргумента. Но это уже не совсем, как у strip(). Мне вообще очень нравится ответ jfs.

Comment: Это решается `re.escape` :) Я же писал уже :

Comment: @ReinRaus добавьте в ответ плиз. НИ РАЗУ не использовал re.escape)))

Comment: Эмммм.... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489372/481

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы поддерживать текст с несколькими строками, пустые строки, произвольные пробельные символы:

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.fullmatch(r'\s*(.*?)\s*', s, re.S).group(1) for s in ['', '  ', ' a\nb\t']]
['', '', 'a\nb']
```

Поведение `*` по умолчанию жадное: `\s*` старается потребить как можно больше входных символов. `*?` -- это не жадная разновидность, поэтому `.*?` в этом случае не будет содержать пробелов по краям.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам нужен такой вариант регэкспа.

```
regex = re.compile(r'^(\s*)([^ ]*)(\s*)$')
```

Comment: А что будет со строкой `"   some text   "`? `r = re.compile("^\s+(\S+)\s+$"), s = r.search(" some text ") -> s is None`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def reStrip( text, delim=" " ):
    return re.sub( '^['+re.escape(delim)+']*|['+re.escape(delim)+']*$', "", text )
reStrip( "   sdf   ", " s" ) // 'df'
```

Answer (score 0):

короткий ответ - звездочки нужно перенести в скобки, то есть, "правильнее" регулярка выглядит так

```
regex = re.compile(r'^( *)([^ ]*)( *)$')
```

Comment: Текст: `   мама мыла раму                            ` с кучей пробелов слева и справа. Блин. Парсер кривой маркдауна. В-общем если несколько слов в тексте, то регулярное выражение не справится.

Comment: Да, не справиться, но задача изначально стояла другая.

Comment: Хм. Ну да. Посмотрел ревизии вопроса- он был раньше страшным.

Comment: а вот если делать strip, то тут классическая рекомендация - делать в два приема - отсекать начало и конец по отдельности.

Answer (score -1):

Достаточно там регулярки

```
 r'\S+'
```

Такой пример

```
import re
result = re.search(r'\S+', '    asdfgh   ggggggg    oooo')
print result.group(0)
```

выведет

```
asdfgh
```

Comment: Ага,  а для строки  'asdfgh   ggggggg    oooo' c пробелами по краям, выведет опять же 'asdfgh", а не  'asdfgh   ggggggg    oooo'

Comment: @Visman, но `'    asdfgh   ggggggg    oooo'.strip()` выведет нечто совершенно иное

Comment: @andy.37, так формулируйте вопрос верно сразу и на русском языке, а не ждите пока вам формулировку вопроса изменят другие пользователи сайта.

Comment: @Visman, вы получателя перепутали )

Comment: @BOPOH, не проснувшийся был.